# Should ConnectionToken in SignalR be protected when using SSL for transport?

Tags: ssl, websocket, signalr

What exactly is the role of the ConnectionToken in SignalR?

I inspected the SignalR handshake in fiddler and saw that a ConnectionToken is being passed in the response to the negotiate request and then passed in all subsequent requests.

However, when inspecting the WS frames, I saw no trace of that ConnectionToken. Is it because fiddler hides it from me or is it simply not passed on the wire?

If it's because it's not passed on the wire, what is its' purpose?
If it is passed on the wire, is it considered to be a secret even if the transport is over ssl? how can an attacker exploit that token?

Answer (score 1):

Connection token is an encrypted string containing the connection id and, if available, user name. It needs to be sent with each http request sent by the client to the server. If a server receives a request without the connection token or if it cannot decrypt the connection token it will reject the request. To read more on connection token and how it works take a look at [this article](https://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/security/introduction-to-security#connectiontoken).

You don't see the connection  token in websocket frames since the connection token was validated when the websocket was opened (the `connect` request) and further validation is not needed (it is impossible for someone else to use this websocket). You would see the connection token again in case the connection was dropped and the client tried to reconnect.

Other transports send more http requests (e.g. for sending messages) and you will see that basically each of these requests (except for ping) contain the connection token. You can take a look at the [SignalR protocol description](https://blog.3d-logic.com/2015/03/29/signalr-on-the-wire-an-informal-description-of-the-signalr-protocol/) I wrote some time ago for more details.

Comment: I found [this comment on a GH issue](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore.Docs/issues/9026#issuecomment-430018389) to be very enlightening when I was trying to understand how the connectionToken plays a part in authentication (spoiler: it does not)